# Incorrect empty datapoints display in a fastline chart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have a fast-line chart series where on X I have `DateTime` and on Y `double` values - series is added to the chart with such method:

```
public virtual bool AddOrUpdateSeries(int caIndex, Series newSeries, bool visibleInLegend)
{
    var chartArea = GetChartArea(caIndex);

    if (chartArea == null) return false;

    var existingSeries = _chart.Series.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == newSeries.Name);

    if (existingSeries != null)
    {
        existingSeries.Points.Clear();
        AddPoints(newSeries.Points, existingSeries);
    }
    else
    {
        newSeries.ChartArea = chartArea.Name;
        newSeries.Legend = chartArea.Name;
        newSeries.IsVisibleInLegend = visibleInLegend;
        newSeries.BorderWidth = 2;
        newSeries.EmptyPointStyle = new DataPointCustomProperties { Color = Color.Red };

        _chart.Series.Add(newSeries);
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I am setting the style for empty point to be shown in red.

The first points that are added to the series are as follows:

[image]

So as you can see, first two points have the same Y value, but in addition -
 first one has `IsEmpty` flag set.

Empty point is added to the series with such piece of code:

```
 series.Points.Add(new DataPoint
 {
    XValue = _beginOADate, 
    YValues = new[] { firstDbPoint.Y }, 
    IsEmpty = true
 });
```

where `_beginOADate` is double OADate value = `42563` = `12/07/2016 00:00 as DateTime`.

The second point's `DateTime` is `15/08/2016 22:20`

When chart is displayed with the beginning of the X axis, everything looks ok as on the picture below - empty datapoint starts at 12/07/2016 and lasts until 15/08/2016. 
[image]

But, when I scroll one position on X, the empty datapoint's red line is not being displayed - instead, whole visible part of empty datapoint's line is displayed as it is non-empty:

[image]

Anybody knows how to fix this behaviour so that the whole line starting from Empty datapoint until first non-empty datapoint would always be shown in red?

Of course the dummy solution would be to add one more extra empty datapoint very close to the first non-empty point, but I don't like that solution.

Comment: Fastline doesn't support all features; does the problem persist when changing to Line?

Comment: Well, when I changed it to `Line` everything works AS EXPECTED - Thanks TaW, but the rendering of the chart is much slower. I have charts with 30k points so when zoomed it slows down quite too much. Anyone knows how to make it more smooth?

Comment: @TaW Can you post your comment as an answer? Actually it solves the problem. It might be useful to the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ChartType.FastLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489249.aspx) is much faster the the simple `Line` chart but to be so fast it makes several simplifications in rendering, which means that not all chart features are supported:

> The FastLine chart type is a variation of the Line chart that
>   significantly reduces the drawing time of a series that contains a
>   very large number of data points. Use this chart in situations where
>   very large data sets are used and rendering speed is critical.
>
> Some charting features are omitted from the FastLine chart to improve
>   performance. The features omitted include control of point level
>   visual attributes, markers, data point labels, and shadows.

Unfortunately [`EmptyPointStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.emptypointstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) is such a '*point level visual attribute*'.

So you will need to **decide** which is more important: The raw speed or the direct and plausible treatment of empty `DataPoints`.

(I have a hunch that you'll go for your 'dummy solution', which imo is a 1st class workaround ;-)